# Не получается создать внутренный класс. В чём ошибка?

Tags: java

У меня есть класс Place, в котором я создаю вложенный класс дверь, который, при вызове isClosed, должен выдавать "дверь находится внутри". Да, я знаю, что выглядит странно но моя задача сделать это именно через внутренний класс (он может быть как нестатическим, так и статическим). Я так думаю, что у меня недостаточно знаний по внутренним классам и видимо переопределять методы внешнего класса нельзя (хотя я видел, что так делают, например в анонимных классах). Подскажите, что делать в таком случае. Может, отправите читать (желательно ссылку, потому что всякие javarush я уже начитался), но я уже просто запутался.

```
package Entities;

public class Place extends Obj {
    String CLOSED = "находится внутри";
    String OPENED = "открытое место";
    
    public Place (String name){
        super(name);
    }
    //по умолчанию у всех объектов типа Place
    public void isClosed(){
        System.out.println(this.getName() + this.OPENED);
    }
    public class Door{
        public Door(String name){
            super();
        }
        @Override
        public void isClosed(){
            System.out.println(this.getName() + this.CLOSED);
        }
    }
}
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
The method isClosed() of type Place.Door must override or implement a supertype method
The method getName() is undefined for the type Place.Door
```

Comment: `The method getName() is undefined for the type Place.Door` - у вас в классе Door нет метода getName. Добавьте соответствующее поле в этот класс и геттер к нему. `The method isClosed() of type Place.Door must override or implement ...` - у вас класс Door ни от чего не наследуется и не реализует никакой интерфейс, поэтому нужно убрать @Override у метода isClosed. Добавлять @Override имеет смысл только если есть родительский класс или интерфейс, и у него есть такой же метод. Внешний класс - это не родительский класс, родительский класс - тот который указан через extends.

Comment: Благодарю. Не знаю, можно ли тут как-то пометить мою проблему за решённую. Но в целом вы меня спасли.

Comment: Сейчас ответом добавлю

Answer (score 1):

- `The method getName() is undefined for the type Place.Door` - у вас в классе Door нет метода getName. Добавьте соответствующее поле в этот класс и геттер к нему. Либо отнаследуйте `Door` от `Obj` по аналогии как у вас сделано в классе `Place` (предполагаю, что в `Obj` и поле, и геттер есть).
- `The method isClosed() of type Place.Door must override or implement ...` - у вас класс `Door` ни от чего не наследуется и не реализует никакой интерфейс, поэтому нужно убрать `@Override` у метода `isClosed`. Добавлять `@Override` имеет смысл только если есть родительский класс или интерфейс, и у него есть такой же метод. Внешний класс - это не родительский класс, родительский класс - тот который указан через extends.

И еще одна проблема: к `CLOSED` внешнего класса из внутреннего нельзя обратиться через `this`, т.к. `this` - это сам объект класса `Door`, а у него нет поля `CLOSED`. В данном случае нужно просто убрать this.

Итого получается так:

```
public class Place extends Obj {
    String CLOSED = "находится внутри";
    String OPENED = "открытое место";

    public Place (String name){
        super(name);
    }

    //по умолчанию у всех объектов типа Place
    public void isClosed(){
        System.out.println(this.getName() + OPENED);
    }

    public class Door{
        private String name;

        public Door(String name){
            super();
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void isClosed(){
            System.out.println(this.getName() + CLOSED);
        }
    }
}
```

С классом `Door` в данном случае я вижу такую проблему, что его можно создать только из методов класса `Place`, т.к. `Door` - не статический класс. Это сильно ограничивает его применимость, но иногда бывает нужно.

Если сделать `Door` статическим классом (чтобы можно было создавать объекты этого класса отдельно от объектов `Place`), то `CLOSED` внешнего класса придется сделать статическим полем.